# Can I make a Trello list visible only to me?

Tags: trello, permissions

Ideally I'd like a list on my board that only I can see, or selected organization members.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. You can only control visibility at the board level. However, because you can move cards between boards (open the card, hit `Move...`, and select a new board), it would be possible to emulate that by creating a board with a single list and then moving cards between that and the "real" board.